# Why is this program inserting the values in the message table everytime the page gets reloaded?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

This is the code for a simple chatting system using php, mysql, html, css and javascript. The problem with this code is the everytime the user enters a message and pressed the send button, the message gets send and the value is inserted into the message table but when we refresh the page, the same message again and the message is again inserted into the database. I've tried to manage the architecture but the problem doesn't solve. 
Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chat.css">
</link>


</head> 
<body>
<?php
session_start();
include 'ConnectionPDO.php';
//include_once 'chat.html';
$_SESSION["person"]=$_GET["person"];
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ 


if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
     $message=$_POST['msg'];
     $person=$_GET['person'];   
    try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `sendby`, `sento`, `date/time`, `seen`, `active`, `message`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'No', 'No', ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$_SESSION['username']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$person);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$message);
    $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Message sent!";
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    } 

    }
}else{

}
?>

<div id="main">
<div id="inbox" style="height:400px;overflow:scroll"> 

<?php
$_SESSION["person"]=$_GET["person"];

try {
        $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("select * from `messages` where (`sendby`=? AND `sento`=?) OR (`sendby`=? AND `sento`=?)");
        $stmt2->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['username']);
        $stmt2->bindParam(2, $_SESSION["person"]);
        $stmt2->bindParam(3, $_SESSION["person"]); 
        $stmt2->bindParam(4, $_SESSION['username']);
        $stmt2->execute();

        while($row=$stmt2->fetch()) {
         $sento= $row['sendby']; 
         $message= $row['message']; 
         $time= $row['date/time']; 
         echo $sento;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $message;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $time;
        echo "<br>"; 
        echo "<hr>";
        }
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }

?>

</div>


<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Enter your message here" id="msg"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="btn" id="btn">
</form>
</div>


<script> 
setInterval(myFunction,1000);
function myFunction(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("inbox").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST","sendMsg.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what happens when you refresh a page with a form POST -- it submits the same values again. The simplest solution probably would be to use a [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. You might also consider POSTing the chat via an AJAX hit and then updating the page via JS without doing a full refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your front end(HTML, CSS) and backend(PHP and MySQL/PDO queries) On the same page. Better you can use front end to insert the details and send it to the backend in other PHP files and redirect the result status to front end file by ajax/header/cookies etc.